# Displaying a C++ class via QML in QtQuick2

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am working on a QtQuick 2 application (Qt version 6.2.3). I created one C++ class (let's call this class "Example") that contains the data that my application should deal with. This class can be instantiated several times, representing different datasets to be displayed.

```
class ExampleObject : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString property1 MEMBER property1 CONSTANT)
    ...

    public:
    QString property1;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ExampleObject*)
```

I want to be able to display instances of this class via QML, therefore I created a "Example" custom component with a property pointing to the Example C++ object containing the data I want to display.

```
ExampleComponent {
    property var exampleCppObject // exampleCppObject is a pointer to an instance of ExampleObject

    Label {
        text: exampleCppObject.property1
    }
}
```

To be able to change the Example instance used by the QML component, I created functions to "reinitialize" and "update" the component:

```
ExampleComponent {
    property var exampleCppObject // exampleCppObject is a pointer to an instance of ExampleObject
    property string textToDisplay

    function update() {
        textToDisplay=Qt.binding(() => exampleCppObject.property1);
    }

    function reinitialize() {
        textToDisplay=""
    }

    Label {
        text: textToDisplay
    }
}
```

I call these functions after changing or deleting the Example object pointed by ExampleCppObject, and this works quite fine. But I feel like this isn't best practice, and it seems to me that I am doing things wrong.

**What are better ways of connecting C++ to QML, in the situation I described?**

---

Edit: my main.cpp essentially consists in:

```
MainModel mainModel;
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("mainModel", &mainModel);
engine.load(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
```

Where mainModel is an object which can create different instances of ExampleObject while the application is running.

Comment: You shouldn't reinvent a wheel. Just read the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html). Actually, your code is too broad. I don't understand what a meaning of `ExampleCppObject` property. You never initialize it. Is it a pointer to some instance of `Example` type? The item itself is `Example`, for what you need this property?

Comment: @folibis thanks, I clarified the code. You're right in guessing that exampleCppObject is a pointer to the C++ object. The reason I need this property is to be able to change the instance being displayed, which seems impossible with the solution in the docs (am I wrong?)

Comment: what did you write in `main.cpp` ?

Comment: @Parisa.H.R I added it to my question

Comment: @user47679 I suggest you try my method too. use `qmlRegisterType` in main.cpp instead of create object and import it in qml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize the binding `textToDisplay` such that you don't have to call the `upate` and `reinitialize` functions, which seems to be the question you are after:

```
property var exampleCppObject
property string textToDisplay : exampleCppObject ? exampleCppObject.property1 : ""
```

In case you need more complex logic in the future, you can also use braces:

```
property string textToDisplay: {
    console.log("log me everytime the binding is reevalutated")
    if(condition1)
       return "invalid"
    else if(condition2)
       return exampleCppObject.property2
    else
       return exampleCppObject.property1
}
```

The best part of this, is that QQmlEngine actually reevaluates the binding for every property that is used in this binding (which has a notify signal), so if crafted correctly, you can largely leave the binding alone (meaning you don't need the `update` and `reinitialize` function)

Comment: I tried a similar solution but unfortunately this tends to provoke segmentation faults when dealing with more complex data structures (namely when ExampleObject has properties which inherit themselves from QObject). Are you aware of a solution to this?

Comment: This kind of solution in itself should not provoke segfaults. Possibly you can improve your runtime by using `QObject->deleteLater()` instead of `delete QObject`, however this seems like a SO question on it's own

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. On a general point of view, would you say that it is good practice to bind QML properties to QObject,ones (either by update/reinitialize functions or by the optimized way you suggest)? Especially compared to Parisa.H.R proposed solution.

Comment: By the way, your suggestion of using QObject->deleteLater() was extremely helpful and I can confirm that I do no longer get segmentation faults, even when directly binding properties.

Comment: @user47679 to answer your question of good practice to bind to QObject's from context property or create in QML. It's very bad practice to create an QObject in QML and then go find it in C++ side. If you have QObject's which can live on their own and whose lifetime can be managed by QmlEngine, then Parisa.H.R. solution will do, but I think for more complex projects you will want to use context properties as you already do, just be gently with deleting ;-)